Why does this incorrect Deref implementation cause an incorrect error message about importing Clone?
Consider this simple Rust program in which I derive Clone for a trivial type (an empty struct) and then invoke .clone() on an instance of it:
use std::clone::Clone;
use std::ops::Deref;
use std::cmp::PartialEq;

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Foo {}

//impl Deref for Foo {}
//impl PartialEq for Foo {}

pub fn main() {
    let f = Foo {};
    let _ = f.clone();
}

Note that I import the Clone trait, because that's required in order to use the .clone() method which is part of it. (Edit: Actually, I've discovered it's not required, which makes the behavior I describe next all the more confusing.) There are also commented-out, incomplete manual implementations of Deref and PartialEq.
If I compile this code, it gives a warning about the unused imports of Deref and PartialEq, but compiles successfully and produces no output, as expected.
But if I uncomment the incomplete Deref implementation, I get two compiler errors, one that makes sense and one that doesn't:
error[E0046]: not all trait items implemented, missing: `Target`, `deref`
 --> src/main.rs:8:1
  |
8 | impl Deref for Foo {}
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ missing `Target`, `deref` in implementation
  |
  = help: implement the missing item: `type Target = /* Type */;`
  = help: implement the missing item: `fn deref(&self) -> &<Self as Deref>::Target { todo!() }`

error[E0599]: no method named `clone` found for struct `Foo` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:13:15
   |
6  | pub struct Foo {}
   | -------------- method `clone` not found for this struct
...
13 |     let _ = f.clone();
   |               ^^^^^ method not found in `Foo`
   |
   = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope
   = note: the following trait defines an item `clone`, perhaps you need to implement it:
           candidate #1: `Clone`
help: trait `Clone` which provides `clone` is implemented but not in scope; perhaps you want to import it
   |
1  + use std::clone::Clone;
   |

The first error tells me that my Deref implementation is bad, which is correct. But the second one tells me that "trait Clone which provides clone is implemented but not in scope", which is false, as we can clearly see in the code and in the fact that it compiled before.
The Deref trait seems special in this regard; if I uncomment the incomplete PartialEq implementation instead, I get a correct error message about the bad implementation and nothing about Clone, as expected. The same seems to be true for other traits (I also tried Add, for example). If I include multiple incomplete implementations, I get one error message for each, and I get an incorrect error message about Clone whenever Deref is one of the ones I include. I also get the wrong error message when I add a field to Foo. It also appears that Clone itself is not special; if I auto-implement PartialEq and invoke it by calling foo1.eq(&foo2), I get the same pair of behaviors (where it normally works, but a bad Deref implementation ruins it). And the same also happens when I implement Clone manually.
What's happening here? Is it a bug in the compiler that I'm being told to import something I'm already importing, or do I misunderstand the situation somehow?

It is meaningless to argue about the meaning of wrong code; if you fix the first error the second disappears too. So at most this is a diagnostics issue, and I don't know if it will even be considered worth fixing (though you can try reporting it).

@ChayimFriedman: I'm not aware of anything that says errors should be resolved in any particular order; absent which, one could waste considerable time tackling completely nonsense errors (such as the latter two here).  To me, this is absolutely a diagnostics bug that should be logged (on the project's issue tracker) and resolved.

@eggyal Which is why I said it can be reported. I agree it's a bug, but it might not be a particularly high-priority one, even among diagnostic bugs; there are plenty of cases where there is a redundant misleading error, and while we try to fix them as we find them we cannot eliminate them for good.

Anyway, I suspect this is because the Deref impl without Target confuses the compiler which sets the Target type to the error type, which somehow takes precedence in autoderef over the Clone impl.

Thank you both! The discussion above confirms my suspicion that this is a bug, and I have filed this bug report over it: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/131003

If one of you wants to write an answer just confirming that it's a bug, I'll go ahead and accept that answer.

There is an existing issue: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/127798

I could imagine that a botched Deref implementation could leave the compiler in bad enough state that method lookup would not work as expected even if the deref isn't needed.

@MegaWidget you can answer your own question

Yes, it's a compiler bug.
Based on the discussion in the comments, I assumed this was indeed a bug and filed a bug report with Rust: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/131003
A fix was pushed the next day and is awaiting review: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/131024
